# ADODB PHP LEFT JOIN

Tags: php

In ADODB PHP active record all of my left joins print blank.

---

Example:

```
$umgp = new ADODB_Active_Record('modulesActionsGroupPermissions', 'CliDB');                        
$umgp->TableHasMany('modulesActionsGroupPermissions', 'userGroups');
$umgp->Find('groupID IN (?)',array('1','2'));        
print_r($umgp);
die();
```

---

Result prints this:

```
DaoMaster Object
(
    [_dbat] => 21
    [_table] => modulesActionsGroupPermissions
    [_tableat] => modulesActionsGroupPermissions
    [_where] => 
    [_saved] => 
    [_lasterr] => 
    [_original] => 
    [foreignName] => daomaster
    [lockMode] =>  for update 
    [groupid] => 
    [actionid] => 
)
```